# adding stock data to amibroker using c#

Tags: c#, createobject, instantiation, stock

I have had a hard time getting and answer to this and i would really , really appreciate some help on this.

i have been on this for over 2 weeks without headway.

i want to use c# to add a line of stock data to amibroker but i just cant find a CLEAR response on how to instantiate it in C#.

In VB , I would do it something like;

```
Dim AmiBroker = CreateObject("Broker.Application")                
sSymbol = ArrayRow(0).ToUpper
Stock = AmiBroker.Stocks.Add(sSymbol)
iDate = ArrayRow(1).ToLower
quote = Stock.Quotations.Add(iDate)
quote.Open = CSng(ArrayRow(2))
quote.High = CSng(ArrayRow(3))
quote.Low = CSng(ArrayRow(4))
quote.Close = CSng(ArrayRow(5))
quote.Volume = CLng(ArrayRow(6))
```

The problem is that CreateObject will not work in C# in this instance.

I found the code below somewhere online but i cant seem to understand how to achieve the above.

```
Type objClassType; 
objClassType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Broker.Application");
// Instantiate AmiBroker
objApp = Activator.CreateInstance(objClassType);
objStocks = objApp.GetType().InvokeMember("Stocks", BindingFlags.GetProperty,null, objApp, null);
```

Can anyone help me here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The VB code uses something called late binding against a "COM IDispatch" compatible component. Late binding is not supported by C# (up to C# version 3). The C# compiler only compiles code it knows how bind to (called early bind).

To do what you want to do, it would be easier to generate a proxy dll via Visual Studio - select **add reference** on a project, then select the tab **COM**, and then search for that ami broker component in the list. This will generate a proxy dll which you can program against using similar code as the one you have showed for VB.

In C# 3.0, you'll discover that you sometimes have to use `Type.Missing` and that you have to do some additional explicit casting, even though you'd think that it doesn't seem logical.

C# 4.0 has something called `dynamic`, which allows you to write much cleaner code when accessing COM components.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer here for the code:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20101274/1581495

I actually use this method now. I save text files from MetaTrader then import them realtime into AmiBroker. Doing it this way is essentially like importing quotes using the ASCII import, so you'll need to make sure that you prepare your import format file. For me, a line of sample data looks like this:

```
EURAUD,20170607,00:00:00.4885,1.50174,1.50231,1 //Symbol, Date, Time (HH:MM:SS.tttt), Bid, Ask, Volume
```

I use the default.format file, which looks like this:

```
$FORMAT TICKER,DATE_YMD,TIME,CLOSE,AUX1,VOLUME
$SEPARATOR ,
$AUTOADD 0
$BREAKONERR 0
$SKIPLINES 0
```

Find the guide and some examples here on importing and formats:

https://www.amibroker.com/guide/d_ascii.html

EDIT: this might also help with importing

http://www.amibroker.com/kb/2016/01/23/how-to-create-custom-import-definition-for-ascii-importer/