# VB.Net Equivalent code For Mid$(string, start position, end position) = New String

Tags: vb.net, string, vb6

In VB6 I can use following code to change part of string with another string..

For example:

```
Dim strTest As String
strTest = "abc"
Mid$(strTest, 2, 1) = "x"
' now strTest Value will be "axc"
```

Is there any VB.Net equivalent for above? String.Replace will replace all instance but I don't want that.

Comment: i don't understand why i get down vote? is asking question is wrong here?

Comment: Your question was down voted because it seems that you didn't do any research on your own.  Typing _VB.Net Mid$_ in Google returns many many hits that would have helped you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [VB.NET Mid statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xz5s6003(v=vs.90).aspx). The code below will produce the same results as your VB6 code.

```
Dim strTest As String
strTest = "abc"
Mid(strTest, 2, 1) = "x"
```

Comment: Dear sir, Mid is not vb.net sole function. you need to use vb6 names space what i don't want to use :(

Comment: It is the MID *statement*, not the function.  Has been part of Basic for a very, very long time.  And still is today, nothing to do with "vb6 names space".  The VB.NET compiler transforms it into a helper method call, Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.StringType::MidStmtStr(), included with the Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll assembly.  Which you always use in a VB.NET program.

Comment: @HansPassant The OP is [against using VB in VB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25951997/equivalent-code-of-createobject-in-vb-net#comment40629814_25951997) for some reason.

Comment: @HansPassant, pardon me, i am sorry that's my fault. But i don't know for some wired reason vb.net shows error on that statement/line. But not it is not showing ;( very wired. Thanks though

Comment: @user - clearly you did a very shoddy job of asking this question.  [Read this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).