# Read Amibroker price volume data using python

Tags: python, stocks, trading, amibroker

I would like to read the price volume data of Amibroker stock symbols using python. I cannot find anything useful on google for doing this. Anyone can help?

Comment: This isn't really a coding question.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/527703/how-can-i-get-stock-quotes-using-google-finance-api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### `Cool:` Just do not hesistate to fully open the box of delicious candies

AmiBroker, as other trading frameworks do either, can provide data, but it is a compact ( ~ 3.5 MB `.EXE` +  `.DLL`s), performance optimised executable that does not, unlike Java or .NET programs, require any internal VM to interpret the user-processes on a byte-code level, but runs on a full steam on machine-code level.

While AB provides several integration options for Data-access, **my advice** -- after spending about last 12 years in quantitative R&D -- would be: **go distributed** ( forget to spend your time to implement just a particular access to some data-element ( Volume ) and do not further rely on state-sharing -- rather start using intelligent inter-process communications & smart inter-agent signalling **`python`**-asks, **`AmiBroker`**-replies ad-hoc etc. ).

### Python side -- for free <sup>( . . . be it run on the `localhost` or another continent )</sup>

This is known to be pretty simple and sooooo flexible as per both extending and tools/modules availability, that lets me straight skip it here, you know better a priori what you need on python side and most of the needs have been implemented already or is quite simply added as a few module extensions.

### AmiBroker side -- the harder part

Tomasz Janeczko wrote a lot on a particular mode of AB integration - the **`DLL`**-based one. Why? DLL-s allow one the smooth and fully controllable integration one needs in a system-to-system communication architecture.

> *(cit.:)* "... translate ... to C/C++ language and compile as `AFL` plugin **`DLL`**. Doing so requires some C/C++ programming knowledge, a C/C++ compiler (free Visual Studio Express or GNU tools can be used) and AmiBroker Development Kit (**ADK**).
> **ADK** contains instructions how to write your own `AFL` plugin along with code samples that are ready-to-compile. Some C/C++ knowledge is required though.
>   **ADK** is freely downloadable from
>   http://www.amibroker.com/bin/ADK.exe (self-extracing exe)
>   or
>   http://www.amibroker.com/bin/ADK.zip (zip archive)
>   **NOTE: ADK** is not for the beginners. It is for programmers (i.e. for people who already wrote some C/C++ code in their life)."

Be careful:

> When plug-in `DLL` is written with AmiBroker Development Kit (**ADK**) it is usually compiled with Microsoft C runtime library. The “problem” is that depending on compiler used, different versions of C runtime are required for the `DLL` to be loaded by the operating system.
>   For example Visual C++ 6.0 links against `MSVCRT.DLL` that is commonly found in all Windows starting from Windows XP so you can “forget” about installing the runtime. But when plugin is compiled with more recent Visual C++ 2005, 2008 or 2010 then required C runtime library is almost never present on target ( client ) computer.
>   
>   In order to load the plugin compiled with VC2005 or higher, one must install proper run-time library on the client computer. The runtime must exactly match the compiler version and eventual compiler service pack used to compile the `DLL`, otherwise operating system will not load the `DLL`. Appropriate runtimes (`vcredist.exe`) are in:
> `VCInstallDir\SDK\v2.0\Bootstrapper\Packgages\vcredist_x86`
>   or
>   
> `VCInstallDir\SDK\v2.0\Bootstrapper\Packgages\vcredist_x64`
>   
>   or similar directory (depending on VC version being used). Then such `vcredist.exe` must be shipped with the DLL to all clients for their installation.
>   
>   Alternatively can compile `DLL` with a static runtime library.
>   
>   There is a freeware tool called Dependency Walker (http://www.dependencywalker.com/) that allows to check what given `DLL` needs to be loaded by the operating system.

Plus -- you absolutely need to make sure that your plugins use “Multithreaded DLL” run-time library. Godd news is, Visual C++ compilers (2005 and 2010) do not allow to choose single-threaded runtime anymore.

So -- put your `DLL` into “Plugins” directory and if it does not show up in the data source list it means that its bitness ( 32bit / 64bit ) is not matching the AmiBroker one.

Having `DLL`-mode ready to be used, one can implement a `DLL`-based wrapper for almost any smart-messaging framework alike **`ZeroMQ`**, **`nanomsg`** et al and having achieved this, your imagination is the only limit in further system-to-system communications with **`python`**.

- **`python`**-asks, **`AmiBroker`**-replies
- **`AmiBroker`**-asks,  **`python`**-replies
- **`AmiBroker`**-asks,  **`remote-GPU`**-replies
- **`AmiBroker`**-asks,  **`remote-AI/ML`**-predicts and publishes targets for trade-setup / trade-mangement ( works with low latency times -- tens of `[ms]` -- suitable for even low-intensity HFT strategies ),
- **`AmiBroker`**-publishes,  **`remote-ComputingGrid`**-processes and signals to whoever else for any post-processing

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your scenario is, but you have a few options.

Ultimately, all the information stored about a stock is on the AB database, which you can access from your AFL. So, to get the value into Python, you can create a text file, that your Python code can read.

Your next option is to interact directly with the AB COM object, see the guide. I don't know how that can be done in Python.

Here's the COM object guide, under Quotation:

> Quotation class represents one bar of price data

https://www.amibroker.com/guide/objects.html

The link below is an idea from another answer I've posted regarding AB COM interop.

[Equivalent code of CreateObject in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13719579/equivalent-code-of-createobject-in-c-sharp/20101274#20101274)

Sethmo

Comment: A file-based handover of data-elements is doable, but it's 3rd Millenium and such automation could have a better tailored architecture, couldn't? The COM-based integration model is a step better, while limits the deployment to python residing on the same <localhost> as the AmiBroker, which restricts processing performance (+introduces an ultimate dependency on having the whole top-bottom COM-based integration path always available in both near and further future = ( Microsoft O/S+API +AmiBroker +(python)win32com.client) so a thrilling future **(happened to DDE not implemented in Vista64)** )

Answer (score 1):

You can try change this javascript which I modify Amibroker example to Python. This javascript will dump the Amibroker database to a file. This script will you some idea how the database in Amibroker can be accessed.

```js
function FormatFloat( number )
{
 number = 0.001 * Math.round( number * 1000 );
 str = number.toString();
 return str.substring( 0, str.indexOf(".") + 4 );
}

var oAB = new ActiveXObject("Broker.Application"); 
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"); 

/* Indicate the location and file name for the database dump. */
file = fso.OpenTextFile( "C:\\Info.txt", 2, true ); 

/* Indicate the location and name of the database to dump. */
oAB.LoadDatabase("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\AmiBroker\\Data");

var oStocks = oAB.Stocks; 
var Qty = oStocks.Count;

for( i = 0; i < Qty; i++ ) { /* Loop through all the stocks in the database. */
 oStock = oStocks(i);
 for (j = 0; j < oStocks(i).Quotations.Count; j++) { /* Loop through all the ohlcv in each stock. */
  oQuote = oStock.Quotations( j );
  var oDate = new Date( oQuote.Date );
  file.WriteLine( oStocks(i).Ticker + "," + 
   (oDate.getMonth()+1) + "/" + oDate.getDate() + "/" + oDate.getFullYear() + "," + 
   FormatFloat( oQuote.Open ) + "," + 
   FormatFloat( oQuote.High ) + "," +
   FormatFloat( oQuote.Low ) + "," +
   FormatFloat( oQuote.Close ) + "," + 
   Math.round( oQuote.Volume )  );
 }
} 
file.Close(); 
WScript.Echo("Export finished" ); ​
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Price Volume of the ticker (Formula: Close x Volume)

  Price_Volume = C*V

//Price Volume of specific ticker (eg. SPY) (Formula: Close x Volume)

  Price_Volume_SPY = foreign("SPY","C")*foreign("SPY","V")

//Yesterday Price Volume of specific ticker (eg. SPY) (Formula: Close x Volume)

  Yesterday_Price_Volume_SPY = Ref(foreign("SPY","C"),-1)*Ref(foreign("SPY","V"),-1)
```